# MySQL find and replace not working as expected (serialized data)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, serialization, syntax, syntax-error

Im trying to create a MySQL search and replace script for my wp_postmeta db table.

I need to search this fields that are similar to this.

```
a:2:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"name";s:15:"Personalisation";s:4:"type";s:7:"heading";s:11:"description";s:0:"";}i:1;a:13:{s:4:"name";s:8:"Initials";s:12:"title_format";s:5:"label";s:4:"type";s:11:"custom_text";s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:18:"description_enable";i:0;s:8:"required";i:1;s:3:"min";s:1:"1";s:3:"max";s:1:"4";s:12:"restrictions";i:1;s:5:"price";s:1:"3";s:10:"price_type";s:14:"quantity_based";s:12:"adjust_price";i:1;}}
```

and replace the `"required";i:1;` with `"required";i:0;`

Im using phpmyadmin to create and run the script but so far I cannot get what I have written to run with the semicolons in there.

This is what ive come up with so far;

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, '"required";i:1;', '"required";i:0;')
WHERE meta_key = '_product_addons';
```

and get the error (removing the semicolons fixes this but then doesn't match anything):

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''"required")' at line 1
```

I've tried using \ to escape them and this doesn't work, this is about as far as my knowledge goes with MySQL so hoping someone can help?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try declaring the search and replace strings as variables? `SET @search = '"required";i:1;'` for example and then select it and see the output, then do the same for the replace string and try again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK so I've found out that this actually works fine but won't work when using the Simulate option, can anyone explain why this is?